# Remove/Disable "Two-factor authentication" and "Personal Data" from /Identity/Account/Manage page

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm developing web application using ASP.NET Core MVC (.NET 5) and Identity for user management. If I navigate to /Identity/Account/Manage page I can see 5 options:

- Profile
- Email
- Password
- Two-factor authentication
- Personal data

I would like to remove **Two-factor authentication** and **Personal data** options from the page. And also remove or disable the access to these functionalities. How can I do it?

**Edit:**

I added new scaffolded item and check Account/Manage/Layout, and then I remove the `<li>` elements for **Two-factor authentication** and **Personal data** but /Identity/Account/Manage/PersonalData and /Identity/Account/Manage/TwoFactorAuthentication links are still accessible.

Comment: `but /Identity/Account/Manage/PersonalData and /Identity/Account/Manage/TwoFactorAuthentication links are still accessible.`Maybe you can remove them in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have managed to disable the pages, following the instructions that appear in the documentation ([Disable a page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#disable-a-page)), but with a little changes.

I added these new scaffolded items:

- Account/Manage/Layout (previously added)
- Account/Manage/DeletePersonalData
- Account/Manage/Disable2fa
- Account/Manage/DownloadPersonalData
- Account/Manage/EnableAuthenticator
- Account/Manage/PersonalData
- Account/Manage/ResetAuthenticator
- Account/Manage/TwoFactorAuthentication

For DeletePersonalData, Disable2fa, DownloadPersonalData, EnableAuthenticator, PersonalData, ResetAuthenticator and TwoFactorAuthentication I removed all content from **.cshtml** and **.cshtml.cs** files, leaving them **empty**.

In **_ManageNav.cshtml** file I removed these list items:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link @ManageNavPages.TwoFactorAuthenticationNavClass(ViewContext)" id="two-factor" asp-page="./TwoFactorAuthentication">Two-factor authentication</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link @ManageNavPages.PersonalDataNavClass(ViewContext)" id="personal-data" asp-page="./PersonalData">Personal data</a></li>
```

In **ManageNavPages.cs** file I removed the following properties and methods:

```
    public static string DownloadPersonalData => "DownloadPersonalData";
    public static string DeletePersonalData => "DeletePersonalData";
    public static string PersonalData => "PersonalData";
    public static string TwoFactorAuthentication => "TwoFactorAuthentication";
    public static string DownloadPersonalDataNavClass(ViewContext viewContext) => PageNavClass(viewContext, DownloadPersonalData);
    public static string DeletePersonalDataNavClass(ViewContext viewContext) => PageNavClass(viewContext, DeletePersonalData);
    public static string PersonalDataNavClass(ViewContext viewContext) => PageNavClass(viewContext, PersonalData);
    public static string TwoFactorAuthenticationNavClass(ViewContext viewContext) => PageNavClass(viewContext, TwoFactorAuthentication);
```

As a result I get an 404 HTTP error in the navigator, and this was what I wanted.